# htaccess rewrite a get parameter

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting, rule, typo3-flow

I have already the Typo3 Flow .htaccess
    #
    # TYPO3 Flow context setting
    #

```
# You can specify a default context by activating this option:
# SetEnv FLOW_CONTEXT Production

# If the root path is not the parent of the Web directory,
# TYPO3 Flow's root path must be specified manually:
# SetEnv FLOW_ROOTPATH /var/www/myapp/

#
# mod_rewrite configuration
#
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

# Enable URL rewriting
RewriteEngine On

# Set flag so we know URL rewriting is available
SetEnv FLOW_REWRITEURLS 1

# You will have to change the path in the following option if you
# experience problems while your installation is located in a subdirectory
# of the website root.
RewriteBase /



# Stop rewrite processing no matter if a package resource, robots.txt etc. exists or not
RewriteRule ^(_Resources/Packages/|robots\.txt|favicon\.ico) - [L]

# Stop rewrite process if the path points to a static file anyway
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule .* - [L]

# Perform rewriting of persistent private resources
RewriteRule ^(_Resources/Persistent/[a-zA-Z0-9]+/(.+/)?[a-f0-9]{40})/.+(\..+) $1$3 [L]

# Perform rewriting of persistent resource files
RewriteRule ^(_Resources/Persistent/.{40})/.+(\..+) $1$2 [L]

# Make sure that not existing resources don't execute TYPO3 Flow
RewriteRule ^_Resources/.* - [L]

# Continue only if the file/symlink/directory does not exist
RewriteRule (.*) index.php

</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>

# prevents Apache's automatic file negotiation, it breaks resource URLs
Options -MultiViews

</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_setenvif.c>

# Redirect authorization header when PHP is running as CGI
SetEnvIfNoCase Authorization "Basic ([a-zA-Z0-9\+/=]+)" REMOTE_AUTHORIZATION=$0

</IfModule>

ErrorDocument 500 "<h1>Application Error</h1><p>The TYPO3 Flow application could not be launched.</p>"
```

So i think this is the standard flow htaccess.
Is there a possibility to define own rules?

My htaccess skills are quite bad. What do i have to edit do replace a GET parameter

```
show?path=
```

My Domain looks like 
    http://domain.com/show?path=/test/test2

It should look like
    http://domain.com/show/test/test2

thanks in advance, regards

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can extend .htaccess and if you have mod_proxy enabled adding this line should be enough (check what [[P] flag does](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_p))

```
# Add this line
RewriteRule ^show/(.*)$ /show?path=/$1 [P]

# Continue only if the file/symlink/directory does not exist
RewriteRule (.*) index.php
```

But you should handle this kind of stuff using [Routing](http://flowframework.readthedocs.org/en/stable/TheDefinitiveGuide/PartIII/Routing.html) - then you will have uri builder and rewriting handled by framework.

If your `path` is just string argument in showAction, ten adding to `My/Package/Configuration/Routes.yaml` (and setting subroutes in main `Configuration/Routes.yaml` above Flow subroutes)

```
-
  name: 'show'
  uriPattern: 'show/{path}'
  defaults:
    '@package':    'My.Package'
    '@controller': 'Standard'
    '@action':     'show'
    '@format':     'html'
  appendExceedingArguments: true
```

If it's property of object you have example in link above.

The only problem is that `/` in argument (like '/test/test2') won't work with route above.. To handle arguments containing `/` you might need to create your own [Route Part Handler](http://flowframework.readthedocs.org/en/stable/TheDefinitiveGuide/PartIII/Routing.html#route-part-handlers).